# Subsets of a topological space which are the boundary of their complement

Tags: general-topology

Is there a name for a subset of a topological space which is the boundary of its own complement? That is, a subset $U$ of a topological space $X$ with $$\partial(X\setminus U)=U.$$

In order to be a boundary the subset must be closed, but trivially not all closed subsets satisfy this property, for example the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. On the other hand, all simple paths and 'simple' shapes of dimension $n$ embedded in $n+1$-dimensional Euclidean space trivially satisfy this property.

Comment: A closed set with empty interior has this property.  Any others?

Comment: @GEdgar That might be sufficient, I'll see if I can prove it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\partial U = \partial X\setminus U$ this is just the same as a set which is its own boundary. So in particular it is closed (all boundaries are) and it has no interior; and these conditions are clearly necessary and sufficient.

Examples include (in $\Bbb R$) :$\Bbb Z$, the Cantor middle third set, any finite set, and $\{0\} \cup \{\frac1n: n \in \Bbb N^+\}$, among others. In the plane you can add lines as examples too. Such sets are called "closed [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) sets".